# How to add pre-installation steps for a custom outlook addin

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

> I am developing an outlook plugin using c# in visual studio. I can make it install-able plugin by publishing it and then install it by running setup.exe file. Before installation, I want a form to be opened to take user credentials and then verify them with third party, the plugin will either continue/cancel the installation based on successfull/ failed authentication. How can I add the pre-install functionality while publishing this plugin?

I've explored and got this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx#Next Steps

It describes how to create a custom installer for a click once application, but it made me confused, either I need to create a separate click ocne project and how can i get an exe file for that application. I would need to run a c# application to install the plugin but i need an exe file.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways for deploying Office COM add-ins:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You can add custom actions to the Windows Installer where you can check user's credentials.

Comment: How can we completely uninstall the plugin from plugin based upon some condition in c# programmatically? @Eugene